# Measuring impedance on VNA

Tags: impedance, measurement, vna

**Question:**
I would like to measure the impedance and phase of an electric piezo tranducer with a resonant frequency of approximately 1MHz - a graph of impedance in Ohms as a function of frequency.
Something like here, but with Ohms on Y axis:

[image]

Source: *A new automatic resonance frequency tracking method for
piezoelectric ultrasonic transducers used in thermosonic wire
bonding*

I have Rigol RSA3030N.

Is it possible to display the results directly on the device without exporting measurements and additional calculations?

**Explanation:**
Based on the [article](https://www.mwrf.com/technologies/test-measurement/article/21849791/copper-mountain-technologies-make-accurate-impedance-measurements-using-a-vna), I came to the conclusion that the most appropriate measurements are in the series configuration, i.e. using the S21 mode. In this mode, it is possible to plot the phase and power of the signal as a function of frequency. Is it possible to enter a formula (like the math function in oscilloscopes) so that the result is in Ohms instead of dB?

In the case of S11 measurements, it is possible to read the impedance, but 1) only in the form of Re + Im, not Z as a vector sum of Re and Im, 2) the results are presented on a smitch chart, not on an x-y chart

Answer (score 0):

Your piezo is a 1-port device, electrically speaking. It doesn't make any sense to talk about S21.

As for S11, if your device doesn't display the results in the format you want, that's kind of the end of that story, isn't it? Either export them and display in something more friendly, or find another device. Your Rigol isn't a purpose-made VNA, it's a spectrum analyzer that happens to have a VNA feature tossed in, which unsurprisingly means that the UI isn't everything you might expect for a VNA.